# SQL query in Pentaho User Console

Tags: sql-server, pentaho

I'm a little confuse about sql query that I create below:

```
SELECT CASE 
WHEN (SELECT TOP 1 CAST(DAJ_KLASIFIKASI AS VARCHAR(25)) FROM BATM112_RKDKLASIFIKASI WHERE DAJ_NODAFTAR = D.DAJ_NODAFTAR ORDER BY DAJ_TKHDE DESC) IS NULL
THEN 'Tidak Diketahui'
ELSE (SELECT TOP 1 CAST(DAJ_KLASIFIKASI AS VARCHAR(25)) FROM BATM112_RKDKLASIFIKASI WHERE DAJ_NODAFTAR = D.DAJ_NODAFTAR ORDER BY DAJ_TKHDE DESC)
END AS STATUS,
CAST(D.DAJ_NODAFTAR AS VARCHAR(25)) AS 'NO ASET', 
(SELECT CAST(PERIHAL AS VARCHAR(250)) FROM KOD_PERALATAN WHERE KODKATEGORI=D.DAJ_KODJENIS) AS 'KATEGORI ASET', 
(SELECT CAST(NAMALAT AS VARCHAR(250)) FROM KAT_PERALATAN WHERE KODALAT=D.DAJ_KODALAT) AS 'KOD ALAT', 
(SELECT CAST(NAMA AS VARCHAR(250)) FROM PASUKAN WHERE KODPASUKAN=D.DAJ_KODPASUKAN) AS PASUKAN
FROM BATM112_DES_AMJENTERA AS D
WHERE DAJ_KODKAT='VTC' 
ORDER BY STATUS
```

When I test this query in SQL Server 2000, the result come out perfectly. But, when I copy and paste this query to create a new data source in Pentaho User Console, it show this error:

```
DatasourceServicelmpl.ERROR_0009
Query validation failed: Query validation failed:{0}
```

Can someone tell me why and how to fix this?

Comment: What happens if you change the apostrophes to brackets after the AS clauses? I.e. "AS [NO ASET]" instead of "AS 'NO ASET'". In standard SQL the apostrophe encloses string literals, not identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

I Have the same problem here with SQL 2008 R2 - Pentaho 5.02
I can't run any query with "order by".
If I run the same query without the "order by", it works.

`SELECT * FROM table01 order by name`        -> Don't work
`SELECT * FROM table01`                      -> Works

Comment: This isn't an answer but an addition to the question itself. Ideally should be a comment or another question by itself.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to do this!

Insert the `Top 100 PERCENT` like this:

```
SELECT Top 100 PERCENT * FROM table01 order by name
```

Regards!